# how to call a plugin after user login in joomla 3.0

Tags: joomla

I am trying to auto create jomsocial albums using a plugin after adding the jomsocial library in plugin in the event function onUserLogin. onUserLogin if i am trying to fetch the $my = JFactory::getUser(); is returs null value. SO the jomsocial library also act same with user values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be sure without any of you code to look at, but the Joomla user plugin uses this when it starts:

```
public function onUserLogin($user, $options = array())
{
    $instance = $this->_getUser($user, $options);
```